# Is it correct to invert, "If I could fly, I would ..." into, "Could I fly, I would ...?"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I know that, "If he should ask about me, ..." can be inverted into, "Should he ask about me, ..." But I am not sure if it works to invert, "If I could fly, I would ..." into, "Could I fly, I would ...?"

Thank you.

Comment: It's a bit quaint, but legit.

Comment: 'Could I but fly, I would' sounds like the authentic quaint version.